# How to obtain the values of a method async c# windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have the following code

```
 async void getLocation1()
    {
        try {

            var geolocator = new Geolocator();
            Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

            // reverse geocoding
            BasicGeoposition myLocation = new BasicGeoposition
            {
                Longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude,
                Latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude                                                
            };                             

            Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(myLocation);
            MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode);

            // here also it should be checked if there result isn't null and what to do in such a case

            PostalCode1 = result.Locations[0].Address.PostCode;
            Country1 = result.Locations[0].Address.Country;
            City1 = result.Locations[0].Address.Town;
            State1 = result.Locations[0].Address.Region;

            guardarLatit = myLocation.Latitude.ToString();
            guardarLong = myLocation.Longitude.ToString();

            await GeolocationWait();

            MessageDialog msgbox3 = new MessageDialog("Latitud: " + guardarLatit + "Longitud: " + guardarLong);
            MessageDialog msgbox4 = new MessageDialog("PostalCode: " + PostalCode1 + " Country: " + Country1 + "City: " + City1 + "State: " + State1);

            geolocation.Add("Latitud: " + guardarLatit);
            geolocation.Add("Longitud: " + guardarLong);
            geolocation.Add("PostalCode: " + PostalCode1);
            geolocation.Add("Country: " + Country1);
            geolocation.Add("City: " + City1);
            geolocation.Add("State: " + State1);

            await msgbox3.ShowAsync();
            await msgbox4.ShowAsync();

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog msgboxE = new MessageDialog("Error");
            await msgboxE.ShowAsync();
            geolocation.Add("Latitud: null");
            geolocation.Add("Longitud: null");
            geolocation.Add("PostalCode: null");
            geolocation.Add("Country: null");
            geolocation.Add("City: null");
            geolocation.Add("State: null");
        }
    }
```

but I need to do it in the same method without the asynchronous method return values I certainly would be some way to tell me all my asynchronous it stops to get that values.

My problem is that when I print the longitude and latitude zero throws me because of what the asynchronous method sends the values certainly not on time.

Thank you

Comment: Are you awaiting getLocation1()?

Comment: I need to get the value of latitude and longitude in real time as the print on a json but always pulls me null because the async method sends the values later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first of all you need to know that you shouldn't use async void.
It is a construction that allows you to use await inside it, but if you await getLocation1() your program will not wait for it.
Instead, you should always use async Task when it's possible. So please try to change getLocation1 to async Task and then, when you await it, after that you will be sure of completed tasks inside of it.

Comment: Thank you, the solution as you indicated to me was to change the method to async Task GetLocation ()